# (click) doesn't work in Angular 5

Tags: angular

I have this template:

```
...
<form>                          
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Trip name</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newTrip.trip_name" name="c_trip_name" id="c_entity_id">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" (click)="addTrip()">Add trip</button>
    </div>
</form>
...
```

But the addTrip method is not fired when using this code in the component:

```
 addTrip() {
  console.log(this.newTrip);
  }
```

If I use input type=submit then I get a full page submitting (not wanted behavior anyway) and still the method not fired.
Any idea what can be the reason for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<form>` tag from code and use it like this.

```
<div>                          
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Trip name</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newTrip.trip_name" name="c_trip_name" id="c_entity_id">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <a (click)="addTrip()">Add trip</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Removing the form has no impact. I have two forms on  this page, the one presented here is the second one.

Comment: The problem was html with jquery and not the actual button, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

This might help you! 
app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

export class Trip {
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  trip: Trip = new Trip;

  addTrip(form: NgForm) {
    console.log(this.trip);
  }
}
```

app.component.html

```
<form #addTripForm="ngForm" no-validate>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Trip name</label>
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="trip.name" name="name" id="name" #name="ngModel">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" (click)="addTrip(addTripForm)">Add trip</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-avrqx5)

Comment: I've tried this as well and with no success, I can't get the action fired.

Comment: The problem was html with jquery and not the actual button, thanks anyway!